# what does below configuration means(jaxb-fluent-api)?

Tags: java, web-services, spring, jaxb, jax-ws

I have below configuration in my POM file. Especially jaxb-fluent-api configuration.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <extension>true</extension>
        <args>
            <arg>-Xfluent-api</arg>
        </args>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.java.dev.jaxb2-commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-fluent-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.8</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Without configuring jaxb-fluent-api entities can be generated from xsd. here what are the **benifits using jaxb-fluent-api**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [`jaxb-fluent-api`](http://code.google.com/p/jaxb-fluent-api-ext) is an JAXB extension, allowing you to generate your code in a *fluent api* style. Now, *fluent api* is a way of designing your class methods, so they always return `this` instead of `void`.

There is a good example on the [project wiki](http://code.google.com/p/jaxb-fluent-api-ext/wiki/Introduction) (I've shortened it a bit for brevity, visit [the site](http://code.google.com/p/jaxb-fluent-api-ext/wiki/Introduction) for full example):

Normal `JAXB`-generated code must be used like this:

```
Project project = factory.createProject();

project.setModelVersion("4.0.0");
project.setGroupId("redmosquito")
project.setArtifactId("jaxb-fluent-api-ext")
project.setPackaging("jar")
project.setVersion("0.0.1")
project.setName("JAXB Fluent API Extensions");
```

With `jaxb-fluent-api` extension, you can code the above like this:

```
Project project = factory.createProject()
    .withModelVersion("4.0.0");
    .withGroupId("redmosquito")
    .withArtifactId("jaxb-fluent-api-ext")
    .withPackaging("jar")
    .withVersion("0.0.1")
    .withName("JAXB Fluent API Extensions");
```

That's basically what the *fluent api* is all about.

Comment: I know the answer is not about [`net.java.dev.jaxb2-commons` flavor of `jaxb-fluent-api`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|net.java.dev.jaxb2-commons|jaxb-fluent-api|2.1.8|jar) as mentioned in the question. It's because the project seems to be dead now (the web page is not responding). It's about a library called [`jaxb-fluent-api-ext`](http://code.google.com/p/jaxb-fluent-api-ext/) that is hosted on google-code and basically does the same thing. I think it does not make much difference for the original question, as the basic quastion was about fluent api, not the library itself.